# Mongoose {$exists: false} not working, why?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query:

```
const messageRules = await MessageRule.findOne({
    reservationLength: {$exists: false}
});
```

on the following schema:

```
const MessageRule = new Schema(
    {
        ...,
        reservationLength: {type: Number, default: 1},
        ...
    }
);
```

And the query returns a document with:

```
{
    ...,
    reservationLength: 1,
    ...
}
```

I'm going crazy here.  Does it have something to do with the default setting in my schema?  Any other ideas?

Comment: According to mongoose documentation for findOne() ```Note: conditions is optional, and if conditions is null or undefined, mongoose will send an empty findOne command to MongoDB, which will return an arbitrary document```. But I am not seeing that here. Are you getting the same document everytime?

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug i've encountered with mongoose several times already and i did not find too much information about it (granted i decided not to waste time exploring it).

It occurs with all Default value'd fields, mongoose just automatically sets these values to their defaulted value on the return call (if you check the actual document in the database it will not have this field set).

One easy fix to ease the nerve is to add lean() to the call:

```
const messageRules = await MessageRule.findOne({
    reservationLength: {$exists: false}
}).lean();
```

For some reason this ends up fixing the bug (debatably feature ???)

Comment: Thats works perfectly fine. But can you explain what does leans() do here?

Comment: `lean()` is just a `mongoose` function that returns the raw document and not the wrapper they created that has many more attributes.